# Add header to every request and redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use jquery.

When user log i want to had authorization info in the header.

Seem like when we do a redirect and after we do an ajax call, header is not there anymore

Any reason?

My code

```
$('#loginform').submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  var header = btoa($('#username').val() + ":" + $('#password').val());

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + header
    }
  });


  $.ajax({
    timeout: 1000, //check if really needed
    type: 'get',
    url: '/rest/members/1',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + header
    }

  }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    $("#error-login-form").addClass("hidden");
    var deferredUsername = getNameByUsername();

    $.when(deferredUsername).then(function() {
        window.location = "main.html";
    });

  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

    if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
        $("#error-login-form").removeClass("hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong, you don't put the username and password in the header, and check it on every request, you check it *once*, and then use a cookie with a random ID or something similar to keep track of the user.

Comment: seem like not so bad https://zinoui.com/blog/ajax-basic-authentication

Comment: The example you posted in comments uses [HTTP authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)  It's not the same thing as having a login page that sends login infos to a login script which would set a cookie (like @adeneo says) or a session variable on authentification success. It is unclear what you really need here. But, for sure, the script you posted in your question can't be successful.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can use it in beforeSend. Something like

```
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        var authorizationCode = $.base64('encode', 'userName' + ":" + 'password');
                        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " +authorizationCode);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

                    }
```

As per jQuery Documentation for beforeSend

> A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings objects are passed as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend option will be called regardless of the type of request.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 var header = btoa($('#username').val() + ":" + $('#password').val());
 $.cookie('cookie_authorization', header);
```

and for all you ajax call, add

```
headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + $.cookie('cookie_authorization')
}
```